# Merge 3 classification and regression tree tags?

Tags: support, tags

We have the following tags:

- [cart](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cart) (4 questions)
- [classification-trees](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classification-trees) (2 questions)
- [regression-trees](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regression-trees) (1 question)

Shall we merge them, or make them synonyms? (sorry I'm still not really sure of the distinction.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I would suggest to merge them all under `cart`. Maybe we can add separate tags (`classification` and `regression`) for the type of decision trees used, so that a classification tree might be found by looking at one tag or the other (`cart` or `classification`).

Comment: Do you mean like: `cart-regression` and `cart-classification`? Also can you access the tag tools now that you have over 10K rep?

Comment: @csgillespie No, I was thinking of a general tag, say `cart`, that might be associated with `regression` and/or  `classification`. After all, CARTs are one supervised technique among others for classification. What is the tag tools (or where can it be found)?

Comment: OK just checking. I thought the tag stuff appeared in the tools menu, but they actually appear in the "mod" menu. I'll wait another 24 hours and then merge if everyone agrees (or more likely, disagrees).

Comment: I've updated the tags

Comment: @csgillespie Thank you. (and Thanks to @onestop for suggesting that too)